# Is it possible to send data from a C# application to a website/webserver?

Tags: c#, php, apache, http, post

I hope someone can help me with a query that has been baffling me for ages.

Is it possible to send data from a C# application to a web page while opening the browser e.g. if you had a login form online and wanted to post a username and password to that form from your C# application.

I see something like open browser to the forms page and post the login details to that page from the program then the page can process the form straight away thus logging them on and sending them to the homepage. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: Posting to an Apache PHP server ???????

Comment: Yep, Indeed that's how I create pages, the form would be processed via PHP

Answer (score 9):

yes.

You can communicate to web pages or web servers (or web services) using HttpWebRequest.  This is the actual code I use to get data from a facebook url:

```
internal static string FbFetch(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

But, what you describe is called "HTML screen scraping" and it can be a tedious and brittle approach for building apps.  Tedious because it's hard to wallow through all the UI candy, and brittle because if the page designer changes his page, your screen-scraping will no longer work.

good luck.

Comment: Nice and succinct. I was going to suggest using `WebClient` but this is short enough that there's really no point.

Comment: Thanks, looks useful but I need to open the users default web browser as well, is this feasible?

Comment: Also that is using GET, is there a post equivalent?

Comment: I use HTML agility pack to `http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/` to parse HTML code. I found it excellent for the job, so navigate there if you need to parse the HTML code.

Comment: @AdrenalineJunky - change GET to POST, and you've done the post.  You will also have to format and write the request parameters, of course. As for opening the default web browser, on Windows that is `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url)`.

Comment: @cheeso Thanks, I use that for links but you can't post with it, however I found the solution Jason suggests works well.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question regarding a HTTP post (with attachment), its much tougher - because of the attachments. This is the actual code I use to post images to FaceBook.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new HttpWebRequest with the default properties for HTTP POSTS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL to be posted to</param>
    /// <param name="referer">The refer</param>
    /// <param name="cookies">CookieContainer that should be used in this request</param>
    /// <param name="postData">The post data</param>
    private string CreateHttpWebUploadRequest(string url, string referer, CookieContainer cookies, NameValueCollection postData, FileInfo fileData, string fileContentType)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        // set the request variables
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.55 Safari/533.4";
        request.Accept = "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, */*";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us");
        request.Referer = referer;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        // process through the fields
        StringBuilder sbHeader = new StringBuilder();

        // add form fields, if any
        if (postData != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in postData.AllKeys)
            {
                string[] values = postData.GetValues(key);
                if (values != null) 
                {
                    foreach (string value in values)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            sbHeader.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
                            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}\r\n", key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (fileData != null)
        {
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n", "media", fileData.Name);
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Type: {0}\r\n\r\n", fileContentType);
        }

        byte[] header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbHeader.ToString());
        byte[] footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        long contentLength = header.Length + (fileData != null ? fileData.Length : 0) + footer.Length;

        // set content length
        request.ContentLength = contentLength;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);

            // write the uploaded file
            if (fileData != null)
            {
                // write the file data, if any
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[fileData.Length];
                var bytesRead = fileData.OpenRead().Read(buffer, 0, (int)(fileData.Length));
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // write footer
            requestStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
            requestStream.Flush();
            requestStream.Close();

            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (var stIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    return stIn.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**
And to make it complete, here is the code for posts without the need for a file attachment. Again, I use this code to post to FaceBook.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new HttpWebRequest with the default properties for HTTP POSTS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL to be posted to</param>
    /// <param name="referer">The refer</param>
    /// <param name="cookies">CookieContainer that should be used in this request</param>
    /// <param name="postData">The post data (needs to be formatted in name=value& format</param>
    private string CreateHttpWebPostRequest(string url, string referer, CookieContainer cookies, NameValueCollection postData)
    {
        var sbPostData = new StringBuilder();

        if (postData != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in postData.AllKeys)
            {
                string[] values = postData.GetValues(key);
                if (values != null)
                {
                    foreach (string value in values)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            sbPostData.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var parameterString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbPostData.ToString());
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.ContentLength = parameterString.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.55 Safari/533.4";
        request.Accept = "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, */*";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us");
        request.Referer = referer;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(parameterString, 0, parameterString.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (var stIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    return stIn.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey isn't that somthing similar to code in C# facebooksdk http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks Jason, I tried the code but can't seem to make it work on a https login, is there any difference to posting to https rather than http? Or perhaps the problem was cookies not being created properly or maybe it doesn't redirect properly, something is definitely not working/acting oddly. Any ideas?

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro - no, I created this specifically to communicate to the Facebook Graph API. Not using the facebooksdk. I did get a helping hand from http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/04/12/c-file-upload-with-form-fields-cookies-and-headers.aspx though

Comment: @AdrenalineJunky - When I post to facebook, its using HTTPS, so there isn't a difference. It could be the cookies, however not sure without seeing your code. Also, notice that in the `CreateHttpWebUploadRequest` method, I have `request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` Do you need to set it to `true` for your circumstances?

Comment: Thank you, it all seems to make sense and work for local pages and think my firewall blocked it working for online pages so at least I know it works just need to sort the firewall out.