# Is it possible to send data from a C# client application to an Azure communication services application created in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, azure-communication-services

Is it possible to send data from a C# client application to an Azure communication services application created in JavaScript, or to execute a function defined in the azure communication services application?
Also, is the opposite possible? (sending data from JavaScript to C#)

C# Client Apps →(send data or call function)→ ACS(JavaScript)
C# Client Apps ←(send data or call function)← ACS(JavaScript)
※ACS view in Edge browser

The reason is that I want to notify the end of the meeting from the C# application.
Also because I want to send meeting logs to my C# application.

For screen sharing, I must use the JavaScript version of the Azure Communication services calling SDK.

There was a similar question, will it still be the same way now?
[Is it possible to send data from a C# application to a website/webserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474844/is-it-possible-to-send-data-from-a-c-sharp-application-to-a-website-webserver)

Comment: Yes.  You are trying to make an HTTP connection from a c# app to a JavaScript.  Http contains a URL, Http Headers, and a Body.  Both c# and JaveScript can create and read the three parts of the HTTP message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Azure Communication Services offers two kinds of SDKs:

- Client SDKs for Calling and Chat - available for JavaScript, iOS, Android
- Server SDKs for other modalities - available for JavaScript (meant to be used with Node.js), C#, Java, Python

Your backend can use any of the server SDKs (different microservices can even use different languages) while you can build various frontends for the web, iOS, and Android.

All the SDKs can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/communication-services/concepts/sdk-options